# List of metadata elements created and modified

Tags: metadata

Is there a way to find the list of all metadata elements created and modified on the basis of date or user in a org?

Comment: you can check setup audit trail, It can be exported into CSV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query [SetupAuditTrail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm) to find specific changes, such as...

## Find Changes By User

```
SELECT ... FROM SetupAuditTrail WHERE CreatedBy.Name = 'Brian Fear'
```

## Find Changes By Time

```
SELECT ... FROM SetupAuditTrail WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:10
```

## Find Changes By User And Time

```
SELECT ... FROM SetupAuditTrail WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:10 AND CreatedBy.Name = 'Brian Fear'
```

Note that aggregate results are not allowed, so you can't quickly find answers to things like "How many objects where modified by user X per month?" or things like that. If you need aggregate data, you would want to export the records and manipulate them in your favorite database or spreadsheet application.